# How to get window main menu bar bounds?

Tags: delphi, screenshot, delphi-2010

My aim is to get screenshot of a window from a foreign application without its main menu bar. I'm using this code:

```
BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height, WinDC, xShift, yShift, SRCCOPY);
```

where `xShift` and `yShift` variable values I need to determine by myself because windows in various applications can have different styles, or the system can vary in themes.

So my question is, how can I get coordinates of the bottom left point of the main menu bar of a window (needed for my `xShift` and `yShift` variables)? The point is illustrated on this picture:

[image: This point coordinates are needed]

Or, is there a way to get the client bounds of a window without its main menu bar directly, without this step?

Comment: You need to figure out the proper handle of the forms ClientArea to take screenshoot of it.

Comment: Do you want to do this for this specific app, or all apps in general?

Comment: @SilverWarior, I have only HWND variable of other window

Comment: @David Heffernan, at least for specific, for all is ideal

Comment: It's impossible to do this for all apps

Comment: This doesn't look like it has a menu bar. This looks like it has a control that is made to look like a menu bar. I suppose you might have a chance of looking at all child windows, and if this control is a windowed control, you can find its position and size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the information you need if you have window handle. `GetClientRect` function will give you window client area, but top left coordinate will be (0,0). To translate that into offset you have to get screen coordinates of that point with `ClientToScreen` function and then just subtract window screen coordinates to get offset you need.

```
var
  WindowRect, WindowClientRect: TRect;
  Origin: TPoint;
  Ofs: TPoint;

  Windows.GetWindowRect(Handle, WindowRect);
  Windows.GetClientRect(Handle, WindowClientRect);
  Origin := WindowClientRect.TopLeft;
  Windows.ClientToScreen(Handle, Origin);
  Ofs.X := Origin.X - WindowRect.Left;
  Ofs.Y := Origin.Y - WindowRect.Top;
```

So call to your `BitBlt` function would look like this

```
BitBlt(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, WindowClientRect.Width, WindowClientRect.Height, WinDC, Ofs.X, Ofs.Y, SRCCOPY);
```

I am not sure if `TRect` has `Width` and `Height` properties in Delphi 2010, so you may have to calculate `Width` and `Height` of the `WindowClientRect` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dalija Prasnikar, worked code is:

```
function WindowToBMP(WD: HWND ): TBitmap;
var
  WinDC: HDC;
  WindowRect, WindowClientRect: TRect;
  Origin: TPoint;
  Ofs: TPoint;
begin
    Result := TBitmap.Create;
    GetWindowRect(WD, WindowRect);
    GetClientRect(WD, WindowClientRect);
    Origin := WindowClientRect.TopLeft;
    ClientToScreen(WD, Origin);
    Ofs.X := Origin.X - WindowRect.Left;
    Ofs.Y := Origin.Y - WindowRect.Top;
    with Result, WindowClientRect do
    begin
        Width := WindowClientRect.Right - WindowClientRect.Left;
        Height := WindowClientRect.Bottom - WindowClientRect.Top;
        WinDC:=GetWindowDC(Wd);
        ShowWindow(Wd, SW_SHOW);
        BringWindowToTop(WD);
        try
            BitBlt( Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height, WinDC, Ofs.X, Ofs.Y, SRCCOPY);
        finally
        end;
    end;
end;
```