# Reading the real form dimensions when minimized from maximized state

Tags: forms, delphi, minimize, delphi-10.3-rio

I don't know if you have noticed, but if you maximize a `TForm` and then minimize it, if you read its Width and Height (in this minimized state), you will get values that the Form had before maximization... Which, from my point of view, is wrong.

When my Form is minimized, sometimes it needs to rearrange the controls depending on the `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight` of the Form. So, if the last Form dimensions, and the ones to which it returns from minimization, are those from the maximized state, my controls will be incorrectly arranged if I get the Width and Height of the normalized Form.

Do you know how I can read the real `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight` of the Form when it is minimized from a maximized state?

Comment: Your design is probably flawed if you need to query visual properties for a minimized form.

Comment: Have a look at [`GetWindowPlacement()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowplacement), which reports a window's *normal* position and size when moving from a minimized/maximized state to a restored state.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I analyzed that function and it doesn't seem to return the maximized window size. It returns width and height only for `rcNormalPosition`.

Comment: If you feel the need to rearrange controls, when the size of the form changes then you have a design problem. Panels are your friend when building up a (dynamic) GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this workaround: storing the window dimensions when they are changed and skipping when it is minimized.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    RealClientW, RealClientH: Integer;
    procedure WMWindowPosChanged(var Msg: TWMWindowPosChanged); message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.WMWindowPosChanged(var Msg: TWMWindowPosChanged);
begin
 inherited;
 if not IsIconic(Handle) then begin
  RealClientW:= ClientWidth;
  RealClientH:= ClientHeight;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
 caption:= IntToStr(RealClientW) + ' x ' + IntToStr(RealClientH);
end;

end.
```

Comment: How do you capture the case when the screen dimensions change while you former maximized application is minimized?

Comment: @UweRaabe Indeed... I have to think about it... :(

Comment: ...or a screen is attached/detached, so the desktop size changes?

Comment: I think the answer is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772588/how-to-detect-screen-resolution-change-in-delphi. But the problem is that I need the ClientWith, not the simple Width of the window...

Comment: What keeps you from [using `GetClientRect()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28983667/4299358)?

Comment: @AmigoJack it gives me the normalized window client area when minimized... I think I will rethink my app design...